# Inverting bits of binary string java

Tags: java, binary, bit-manipulation

I want to invert the bits in binary string. For example String 000 should be inverted as 111 and 1101 as 0010. Can anybody help on this?

Comment: That is what `~` operator does. Did you search for 1's complement?

Comment: Where are the bits stored? In what type?

Answer (score 10):

```
s = s.replace('0', '2').replace('1', '0').replace('2', '1');
```

Comment: Yes this worked. If you don't mind Can explain me how does it work?

Comment: @user3259851 If swaps 0's for 2's - so that when 1's are replaced with 0's you still have the 2's to then convert to 0's,, You need the intermediate 2, otherwise after replacing 0's with 1's you'd have a string of all 1's!

Answer (score 3):

**One way:** is using the `replaceAll()` method:

```
String s = "01010";

s = s.replaceAll("0", "x");
s = s.replaceAll("1", "0");
s = s.replaceAll("x", "1");

System.out.println(s);
```

**Output:**

```
10101
```

**Note:**

This can be simplified chaining calls:

```
s = s.replaceAll("0", "x").replaceAll("1", "0").replaceAll("x", "1");
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this, Here input is intger but you could easily convert your string into int I hope it will not be big task.

```
int i= 100;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(~i));
```

Comment: That will drop leading 000s

Comment: depends on the requirement. I don't think leading 000 has any meaning.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this trick to swap 0 and 1

```
String s = "00011";
char[] chars = new char[s.length()];
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    chars[i] = (char) (s.charAt(i) ^ 1); // flip the bottom bit so 0=>1 and 1=>0
String flipped = new String(chars);
// flipped = "11100"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **Apache commons-lang** library you got a handy method to achieve this:

```
StringUtils.replaceChars(mystr, "01", "10");
```

Basically it replaces characters with corresponding characters (correspondence by index).

This is the litte test program

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

public class InvertString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(invert("0001011"));
        System.out.println(invert("000"));
        System.out.println(invert("1101"));
    }

    private static String invert(String string) {
        return StringUtils.replaceChars(string, "01", "10");
    }
}
```

and the output of it is

```
1110100
111
0010
```